# VMWare Fusion W11 apps close on Mac lock

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-11, vmware-fusion

I installed Windows 11 on VMWare Fusion on a Mac M1.

Whenever my mac locks the apps open on the vm close and I have to reopen.  Anyone know how to fix this?